# create an array of twenty integers and fill the array with even numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create an array that prints out the first 20 even numbers but I don't know how to get the arrays to print them and I am only getting an array of twenty 0. So far this is what I have written.

```
int[] mylist = new int[20];
int even = 0;   

while ((even%2 == 0) && (even < 20)){
    even++;
}

System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + mylist[0]);
System.out.println("Element at index 1: " + mylist[1]);
System.out.println("Element at index 2: " + mylist[2]);
System.out.println("Element at index 3: " + mylist[3]);
...
```

Edit: This is what I have done so far:

```
    int[] mylist=new int[20];//establishes the name and length of an array

    for (int even=0;even<mylist.length;even++)

    {
    mylist[even]=even;

        if(even%2==0)
     System.out.println("Even Element: "+even);
}
```

However, instead of printing out twenty even numbers it is just printing out the even numbers between 1 and 20.

Comment: thats because you didn't put anything in mylist

Comment: Which line of code did you think was putting numbers into the array?

Comment: Even if you assigned an element in the while loop, it would only run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create an array of twenty integers and fill the array with even numbers

1. Create an array of 20 int elements:

   ```
   int[] evenNumbers = new int[20];
   ```
2. Fill the array with even numbers:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < evenNumbers.length; i++) {
      evenNumbers[i] = i*2;
   }
   ```
3. Print the elements of the array

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < evenNumbers.length; i++) {
       System.out.println("Element at index " + i + ": " + evenNumbers[i]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop does not sets any value to `mylist`. With java streams you can do it as follows:

```
int[] result = IntStream.iterate(0, i->i+2).limit(20).toArray();
for (int i : result)
   System.out.println(i);

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
...
```

https://ideone.com/HZbGk7

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring the Array but not passing any values into that and the "even" variable getting incremented but where in your code the value is sitting in the "mylist" array

here is code :

```
int[] myList = new int[20];  
    //adding the elements into the Array
    for(int i=0 ;i<myList.length;i++){   
        myList[i] =i;
    }
    for(int j: myList){
      if(j%2==0){      // checking for even 
         System.out.println("even elements:" +j);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentionned marcinj you could use InteStream and applying predicate to it and define as much as you need of predicate :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
IntPredicate isEven = i -> i%2 == 0;

int[] result = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
                        .filter(isEven)
                        .limit(20)
                        .toArray();
for (int i : result)
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

In this exemple i created a intpredicate that define wich values of your stream will be used in this case only even values  : i%2 == 0.